# Projection of upper hemisphere is orientation preserving iff n is even

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

How do I show that the projection map $π : U → R^n ,
π (x_1 , . . . , x_n , x_{n+1} ) = (x_1 , . . . , x_n )$,
is orientation-preserving if and only if $n$ is even

My idea is to calculate the Jacobian of the map and find out if it is greater than zero. Is there a way of doing this without calculating Jacobian?

Comment: You haven't said what $U$ is -- is it supposed to be the upper hemisphere of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$?  What orientation are you using on $U$?

Comment: Orient S^n as the boundary of the closed unit ball and regard U as the upper hemisphere.